# How to correct units in the band.yaml file of QE, to band.yaml of VASP

Tags: vasp, quantum-espresso, phonopy

I see from the phonopy web page [1](https://phonopy.github.io/phonopy/interfaces.html#frequency-default-value-interfaces) that the physical unit systems used for the calculators are different for different codes [1](https://phonopy.github.io/phonopy/interfaces.html#frequency-default-value-interfaces).  On the same page, it is mentioned that "For these sets of physical properties, phonon frequency is calculated in THz." Does it mean that the final unit for frequency and group velocity in `band.yaml` and `gruneisen.yaml` for VASP and QE codes are the same?

I was told by Prof. Togo, the developer of phonopy, that the unit of frequency is considered the same in VASP and QE, but that of group velocity is not.

Could someone please help me: how can I convert the unit of velocity in the QE `band.yaml` file to the units of the VASP `band.yaml` format (THz/Angstrom).

The unit in the VASP `band.yaml` file is THz/Angstrom while in the `band.yaml` file of QE it may be in THz/Bohr (not sure). To make the QE format of `band.yaml` into `VASP band.ymal`, can we do the conversion like below?

```
1bohr = 0.529177249 Angstrom
1/bohr = 1/0.529177249 = 1.88972598857
```

So I need to multiply the velocity in `band.yaml` of QE by 1.88972598857?

My half-finished conversation on the phonopy mailing list can be found here [2](https://sourceforge.net/p/phonopy/mailman/phonopy-users/thread/CAJYci%2BT_NRa0uDqzh-NVyKPq%2BAhy2OdU5oenwARacMspR1SZFA%40mail.gmail.com/#msg37332350)

An example of the VASP `band.yaml` and QE `band.yaml` can be found here [3](https://we.tl/t-aIfkaoJIO3).

Comment: +1. Welcome to our new community and thank you for contributing this question here! We hope to see much more of you in the future !!! We also have chat rooms for [phonopy](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112358/python-based-matter-modeling-software), for [VASP](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109983/vasp), and for [QE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117642/quantum-espresso). Can you say "hello" to us in those rooms so that we remember you're interesting in those programs?

Comment: Finally your we.tl requires us to accept cookies and some terms and conditions. Could you instead put all files relevant to this question in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters) in a folder called `6537` since 6537 is the number in the URL of this question? If you have any trouble, perhaps let me know your GitHub username and I can try to help you.

Comment: Thanks Nike, this is a very unique update. I will drop everything here. I am busy for a meeting. So, I will update the things tomorrow.

Comment: Have you had time now to make that update to the question? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I am understanding the quantum espresso format. I will update it once I finish that.

Comment: kcb, I haven't seen any updates to this question, despite your comment on August 22nd saying that you would. How are things going with this now?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP or someone else would like to provide an answer.